# Looping through td children of a tr element in Python lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following XPath:

```
errors = root.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/text()')
```

Within this HTML (some parts removed for less of a large example)

```
... 
<TABLE  CLASS="datadisplaytable" SUMMARY="This layout table is used to present Registration Errors.">
    <TR>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Status</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><ACRONYM title = "Course Reference Number">CRN</ACRONYM></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><ABBR title = Subject>Subj</ABBR></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><ABBR title = Course>Crse</ABBR></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><ABBR title = Section>Sec</ABBR></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Level</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><ABBR title = "Credit Hours">Cred</ABBR></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Grade Mode</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Title</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">DUPLICATE <ACRONYM title = "Course Reference Number">CRN</ACRONYM></TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">33587</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">UNIV</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">E101</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">941</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Undergraduate Quarter</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">The Drexel Experience</TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE
>
....
```

The output I get is:

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

What's interesting is, if I specify the exact `td` index after the `tr`, like the following code, I get output:

```
errors = root.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td[1]/text()')
```

The output:

```
['DUPLICATE ']
```

It seems like I need to loop through the list, so I tried this, which also did not work.

```
for error in errors:
    print error
```

Comment: why are you selecting text() on the tr if you want to iterate through its children td? you could just do `./table/tr` to get the rows and then for each row `td` to select the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what the question is, but here is a glimpse of what your XPath expressions do.

`/text()` returns text nodes that is *direct child* of current context context node. So, `tr[2]/text()` returns text nodes that is *direct child* of the 2nd `tr` which are just *white spaces and newlines*.

Now contrast the above with `tr[2]/td[1]/text()`, which will return text nodes that is *direct child* of the first `td` in the 2nd `tr`. This is how you got the output `'DUPLICATE '`.

Comment: Apologies if it is unclear. I basically want to print all the text nodes that are direct first of the second `tr`, so, `DUPLICATE 33587 UNIV E101 ..` in one line.

Comment: in that case you can stop your XPath at the `td` and convert it to string, something like : `string(...../tr[2]/td[1])`

Comment: You mean like `str(root.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td[1]'))`? That only returned `[<Element td at 0x10cfe97e0>]` :/

Comment: No. I mean like : `root.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td[1])')`

Comment: Thank you! My final solution consisted of the following: `for i in range(2, 5):
 errors = root.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[' + str(i) + '])')`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage No need to run the xpath multiple times. `root.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td/text()')` will give a list of the text nodes you want.

Comment: @tdelaney mind if I ask you one more thing? The xpath you give me ignores the value in the `<acronym></acronym>` tag, so I get something like `DUPLICATE  33587 UNIV`. As you can see, only `DUPLICATE` is printed as it is outside of the `ACRONYM` tag (which you can see the HTML in my original post.). The right output is `DUPLICATE CRN`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage You can select the TD elements then use a list comprehension to select and join all subordinate text nodes for each. `[''.join(td.xpath('.//text()')) for td in doc.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td')]`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage or alternatively : `[td.xpath('string(.)') for td in doc.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td')]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the content of all the td tags inside the second tr you can use the following xpath:

```
errors = root.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table[4]/tr[2]/td/text()')
```